# How do I allow only one accordion item to be open at a time on a dynamic accordion list?

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

I have a well functioning accordion list that allows me to add new items to the list and they will immediately have the accordion functionality. Although, I would like to have only one accordion item open at a time. All of the answers I've found regarding this have all been for static lists and don't really help with my issue. I apologize if this is a bad question, but I have spent hours on this with no luck and I am out of ideas. Thanks in advance for your help.

HTML: There is more to the HTML. I just added the relevant elements.

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- New accordion item added here -->
    </div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
// Get items
const addAccBtn = document.getElementById('addAccBtn');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

addAccBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newAccItem = document.createElement('div');
    newAccItem.innerHTML = `
        <div class="acc-title">
            <i class="fas fa-trash delete"></i>
            <h3 class="header-click">${accName}</h3>
            <i class="fas fa-sort-down down-arrow"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="acc-info hidden">
            <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
            <h4>Section 1</h4>
            <p>${input1}</p>
            <h4>Section 2</h4>
            <p>${input2}</p>
        </div>
    `;

    container.appendChild(newAccItem);

    let downBtn = newAccItem.firstElementChild.childNodes[5]; // .down-arrow
    let info = newAccItem.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling; // .acc-info

    downBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if(downBtn.parentElement.nextElementSibling == info && info.classList.contains('hidden')) {
            info.classList.remove('hidden');
            info.classList.add('active');
        }
        else {
            info.classList.remove('active');
            info.classList.add('hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

Again, the accordion items will all open and close as they should, i would just like one item open at a time. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe these lines should work

```js
...
    let downBtn = newAccItem.firstElementChild.childNodes[5]; // .down-arrow
    let info = newAccItem.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling; // .acc-info

    downBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

        //here you close all opened accordions ---------------
        document.querySelectorAll(".acc-info.active").forEach(element => {
          if (element !== info) {
            element.classList.remove("active");
            element.classList.add("hidden");
          }
        };
        // --------------------------------------

        if(downBtn.parentElement.nextElementSibling == info && info.classList.contains('hidden')) {
            info.classList.remove('hidden');
            info.classList.add('active');
        }
        else {
            info.classList.remove('active');
            info.classList.add('hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

**_ edit _**

added a if

Comment: Yes I tried that solution and all of the accordions can open, but they cannot close themselves. in fact, the close button causes the element before it to close for some reason.

Comment: try the new solution (i just added a if)

Comment: That solution worked flawlessly. Exactly what i was looking for. Thank you very much for your help.